# Multiple commands with different options using yargs/optimist

Tags: node.js, arguments, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a CLI for a node module using [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) but I'm having difficulty setting two different commands that could be used, one requiring only one parameter, but the other requiring two. Here is what I have so far

```
var argv = require('yargs')
   .option('r', {
       alias : 'reset',
       describe: 'clear data for site(s)',
       type: 'string'
   }).
   option('d', {
       alias : 'dashboard',
       describe: 'copy dashboard for the specified site across all others',
       type: 'array'
   })
   .usage('Usage: $0 -r [string] -d [array]')
   .argv;
```

To reset data I would do

```
node main.js -r mysite
```

But to copy a dashboard I want to be to do

```
node main.js -d theSiteToCopyFrom theSiteToCopyTo
```

or even

```
node main.js -d theSiteToCopyFrom [theArrayOfSitesToCopyTo, , ,]
```

I have looked through the examples given, such as

```
var argv = require('yargs')
    .option('f', {
        alias : 'file',
        demand: true,
        default: '/etc/passwd',
        describe: 'x marks the spot',
        type: 'string'
    })
    .argv
;
```

but I can't see how to specify that multiple parameters are required for different commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just released the nargs feature for yargs, which gives you this capability:

https://github.com/bcoe/yargs#nargskey-count

Comment: Hi @ben Coe - how does it work? Cannot find that in the docs.